# Clear checkboxes after form submitted

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an HTML form with a button and some checkboxes. The values of the checkboxes are passed to the next page via GET parameters. The target of the form submission is a blank page.

```
<form id="myForm" method="get" action="launch.php" target="_blank">
<input type="submit">Launch</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="reset" /> Reset
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="erase" /> Erase
</form>
```

The checkboxes allow the user to reset and/or erase files prior to launching the web app. Since they are "dangerous", I wish to *uncheck* them automatically after the use launches the app. This is to help prevent the user from accidentally erasing or resetting their files twice in a row.

I added an `onClick` action to the button that unchecks the boxes using jQuery. However, they get unchecked *before* the form is submitted, and therefore the values of the boxes aren't included in the GET.

```
<input type="submit" onClick="uncheckBoxes();" />
...
<script>
function uncheckBoxes() {
    $(".checkbox").prop("checked", false);
}
</script>
```

I think I want to do one of two things. Either:

- Use the `$("#myForm").submit()` function to uncheck the boxes, then open a new window. However, I'd have to write code to construct the URL, which is not very scalable (what if I want to add a new checkbox?) and error-prone. Or,
- Somehow hook into the normal form-submission process and execute the `uncheckBoxes` function *after* the new page/tab has opened. Since the page/tab with the form on it remains open, I can still run additional JS code.

What are some solutions to this?

Comment: I find it irrational to use `target="_blank"` on a form. The normal way is to load a new page, otherwise use an Ajax request

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#submit-button').click(function() {
  var url = "launch.php?";
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    url = url + this.name + "=" + this.checked + "&"
    this.checked = false;
  });
  url = url.slice(0, -1)
  console.log(url);
  //wondow.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label>Option 1</label><input name="option1" type="checkbox">
<br>
<label>Option 2</label><input name="option2" type="checkbox">

<button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
```

This is a scalable way!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to prevent twice clicking, you can do something like:-

```
<form id="myForm" method="get" action="launch.php" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" id ="button" onclick = "Clicked(event)" value="Launch">
<input type ="reset" onclick ="button.style.display ='inline'">

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="reset" /> Reset
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="erase" /> Erase
</form>

<script>
var button = document.getElementById("button");
function Clicked(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    button.style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector("#myForm").submit();
}
</script>
```